Множественный выбор вариаций товаров WooCommerce
Делаю магазин авторских переводов книг на WordPress + WooCommerce.
Юридической составляющей не касаемся, вопрос чисто технический.
Логика следующая - в каталоге список книг. Карточки сформированы для вариативных товаров, в каждую вариацию добавлен PDF с переводом на тот или иной язык.
Например: книга "Ночной Дозор", внутри несколько вариаций: испанский, итальянский, французский. Но в самой карточке есть только выбор пункта из выпадающего списка. Т.е. можно выбрать только один перевод, без массового выбора.
Пробовал сделать через WooCommerce Product Add-Ons, но там создается только форма, которая передает значения в корзину, что не дает возможности загрузить купленные PDF (нет привязки формы к конкретному файлу).

Аналитика/учёт вариаций нужен? Цены у варинатов разные?

С ценами ситуация следующая: одинаковая цена для каждой вариации и отдельная цена для суммы всех вариаций. Аналитика понадобится в рамках статистики их покупок.

Что такое "отдельная цена для суммы всех вариаций"? И я правильно понял - это загружаемый/скачиваемый товар?

Получается в карточке есть список переводов, также есть возможность загрузить все вариации по сниженной цене. Да, все товары загружаемые/скачиваемые.

посмотри  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50132928/multi-select-fields-in-woocommerce-backend, https://avada.io/blog/select-multiple-variations/

Благодарю, кажется это то, что нужно! О результатах отпишу позднее.
